# Open URL using authorization header or access token in Javascript/GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to open a URL in new window using GWT/Javascript but it asks for username/password. But i want to bypass it means while opening the URL I want to set the authorization header that will do the login and show the screen after it.
Is it possible? Is there any way to do this so that I can achieve it.